# Batch expert needed file cannot be for looped because of first symbol

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file

I'm having a bit of an issue in the link there is a text file and you will notice that first character is unknown symbol and after batch tries to for loop it only copies that first character and stops there.

Is there a way to tell batch to continue or to warn him before that there is unknown symbol? or even delete it and proceed with the rest of file?

Link to text file:
https://easyupload.io/eknrri

Script:

```
:: Turn echo off
@echo off

:: Enable extensions
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions 
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

:: Set input file
set "InputFile=index.txt"

:: Set output file
set "OutputFile=output.txt"

:: Check if output file exits if it does delete it
If Exist "%OutputFile%" Del "%OutputFile%"

:: Loop through input file
for /F "tokens=* delims=" %%A in ('Type "%InputFile%"') do (
    :: Set line equal to file text
    set line=%%A

    echo !line!
)>>"%OutputFile%"
```

Why does this `powershell -command Get-Content -encoding UTF8 "%InputFile%" > test.txt` not set file to plain text file, but manually save as works?

> Comment from @JosefZ
>
> The file is a binary one. hexdump.exe shows first six bytes 07 00 21
>   00 00 00. Unfortunately, type requires plain text files… – JosefZ

Comment: Stack overflow link for same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60473426/batch-expert-needed-file-cannot-be-for-looped-because-of-first-symbol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### I'm having a bit of an issue in the link there is a text file

Unfortunately the file you have linked to is **not** a text file:

```
$ file index.txt
index.txt: Targa image data - Color 65536 x 65536 x 0 ""
```

It is an image file ([Truevision TGA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truevision_TGA)) according to the header information in the file. It is also damaged or truncated.

> Truevision TGA, often referred to as TARGA, is a raster graphics file format created by Truevision Inc. (now part of Avid Technology). It was the native format of TARGA and VISTA boards, which were the first graphic cards for IBM-compatible PCs to support Highcolor/truecolor display.

---

> after batch tries to for loop it only copies that first character and stops there

`For` loops (together with `type`) are used for processing text files, not binary files like images.

Comment: Thank you, David.